# Recieved email through 3rd party website to use a link to apply for their job, but link is for large listing of companies/jobs

Tags: communication, job-search, hiring-process

I had applied for a job through a website. Today I got an email saying "Hi JoeT, thanks for the interest. Please apply for the position at http://bestjobs4grads.com/jobs.action (enter a keyword)"

I go to this website but it's a directory listing for a whole bunch of jobs and I don't know which company it was that sent me this email. Since the email addressed is anonymized through `bestjobsforgrads` I can't get any information from it.

I can reply to the email, but what exactly should I say? I don't want to come off lazy not having searched through the job posing list but I've applied for so many jobs and the email gave no indication which company it was for.

Comment: You mention that the link asks for a keyword. Had the email to you not included one, I take it? And we have ruled out that this could just be spam, right?

Comment: And could you just apply to the ones you're interested in in the link?

Comment: And lastly, in cases like these, you should just be concise, honest and humble: I'm sorry, but your email does not say the company you're recruiting for (and I have recently applied to multiple companies). May you please let me know for which company and position this is? End of email. You may choose to exclude the part in parentheses, but honestly, if you're scared of working for a company that is unwilling to understand that you apply to multiple companies at once, perhaps this company is not the best fit.

Comment: It looks to me like the URL has not sent properly. If the email is definitely referring to a particular job and not just to the site in general then that link is supposed to go directly to the job.

It sounds like this email has no information about the job at all? If this is the case, simply ignore the email. If you are severely short on potential jobs to apply for then don't worry about replying with:
"Please can you email me with the details of this role? The URL in the last email does not direct me to a specific job so I currently have no information about the position".

Comment: This sounds like a resume-fishing expedition.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the website and it doesn't seem to be a spam.

> I had applied for a job through a website. Today I got an email saying "Hi JoeT, thanks for the interest. Please apply for the position at http://bestjobs4grads.com/jobs.action (enter a keyword)".

Even I am used to applying at job portals and many a time I get mail for interviews from many websites I've never seen before. It seem these websites share the user emails with other websites to provide better and wider services.

Answer (score 0):

> *"but I've applied for so many jobs and the email gave no indication which company it was for."*

The truth does amazing things:

*"You forgot to specify on which of your many job listings you are replying. I have applied to more than one job at your site. Can you me specific for which job application you are interested in hiring me?"*

Nobody telling the truth is lazy. If someone is lazy its them who forgot to write and indicate which company it was for. So no accusations are at stake. But IF they dare to accuse you, you have a perfect excuse and have a winning argument why you did what you did.

Alternatively in the meanwhile you can ask them intelligent questions about the job itself:

*"Can you tell me more about the background of this job and people whom I might be working with? These things were not mentioned in the official listing."*